# AI algorithm for item pickup race

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I would like to build an AI for the following game:

- there are two players on a *M x N* board
- each player can move up/down or left/right
- there are different items on the board
- the player wins who has more items than the other player in as many categories as possible (having more items in one category makes you the winner of this category, the player with more categories wins the game)
- in one turn you can either pick up an item you are standing on or move
- player moves are made at the same time
- two players standing on the same field have a 0.5 pickup chance if both do it

The game ends if one of the following condition is met:

- all the items have been picked up
- there is already a clear winner since one player has has more than half the items of more than half of the categories

I have no idea of AI, but I have taken a machine learning class some time ago.

1. How do I get started on such a problem?
2. Is there a generalization of this problem?

Comment: The winning strategy isn't clear given the information you've provided. Is it better to ignore all items of a category a player already has an item in, or could a player with simply more items win against a player with more categories?

Comment: Also, is there a limit to how many items a player can pick up? There is also the question of how does the game end. Does it end when all of the items are picked up or what?

Comment: @MC You are right. I've updated the question. First: A player can only win with categories, the total sum of items is irrelevant. Second: There is no limit, no. I have added the game termination conditions.

Comment: Is your task to produce the algorithm? Would your algorithm compete with other students' algorithms? Also, is there a time limit per turn involved?

Comment: @Dialecticus No. No. And the last one: No, why? But I guess it should not be too inefficient :)

Comment: If you don't want algorithmic solution then what do you want?

Comment: @Dialecticus It's not my task, but I want to develop an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for clarifing, I'll post a possible answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical choice for adversarial search games like you proposed (called two player zero-sum games) is called [Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) search. From wikipedia, the goal of Minimax is to

> Minimize the possible loss for a worst case (maximum loss) scenario. Alternatively, it can be thought of as maximizing the minimum gain.

Hence, it is called minimax, or maximin. Essentially you build a tree of `Max` and `Min` levels, where the nodes each have a branching factor equal to the number of possible actions at each turn, 4 in your case. Each level corresponds to one of the player's turns, and the tree extends until the end of the game, allowing you to search for the **optimal** choice at each turn, assuming the opponent is playing *optimally* as well. If your opponent is not playing optimally, you will only score better. Essentially, at each node you simulate *every possible game* and choose the best action for the current turn.

If it seems like generating all possible games would take a long time, you are correct, it's an exponential complexity algorithm. From here you would want to investigate [alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning), which essentially allows you to eliminate some of the possible games you are enumerating based on the values you have found so far, and is a fairly simple modification of minimax. This solution will still be **optimal**. I defer to the wikipedia article for further explanation.

From there, you would want to experiment with different heuristics for eliminating nodes, which could prune the tree of a significant number of nodes to traverse, however do note that eliminating nodes via heuristics will potentially produce a **sub-optimal**, but still **good** solution depending on your heuristic. One common tactic is to limit the depth of the search tree, essentially you search maybe 5 moves ahead to determine the best current move, using an estimate of each player's score at 5 moves ahead. Once again, this is a heuristic you could tweak. Something like simply calculating the score of the game as if it ended on that turn might suffice, and is definitely a good starting point.

Finally, for the nodes where probability is concerned, there is a slight modification of Minimax called [Expectiminimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectiminimax_tree) that essentially takes care of probability by adding a "third" player that chooses the random choice for you. The nodes for this third player take the expected value of the random event as their value.

Comment: As an addendum, I skimmed a resource from Cornell, found [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4700/2011fa/lectures/06_AdversarialSearch.pdf), that pictorially explains minimax search and alpha-beta pruning, it seems well-done and may be a good resource. Not adding to my original answer as who knows how long the link will exist for.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach to any such problem is to play the game with live opponent long enough to find some heuristic solutions (short term goals) that lead you to victory. Then you implement these heuristics in your solution. Start with really small boards (1x3) and small number of categories (1), play them and see what happens, and then advance to more complicated cases.

Without playing the game I can only imagine that categories with less items are more valuable, also categories with items currently closer to you, and categories with items that are farthest away from you but still closer to you than to the opponent.

Every category has a cost, which is number of moves required to gain control of it, but the cost for you is different from the cost for the opponent, and it changes with every move. Category has greater value to you if the cost for you is near the cost for the opponent, but is still less than opponent's cost.

Every time you make a move categories change their values, so you have to recalculate the board and go from there in deciding your next move. The goal is to maximize your values and minimize opponents values, assuming that opponent uses the same algorithm as you.

The search for best move gets more complicated if you explore more than one turn in advance, but is also more effective. In this case you have to simulate opponents moves using the same algorithm, and then choosing your move to which opponent has the weakest counter-move. This strategy is called [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax).

All this is not really an AI, but it is an road map for an algorithm. Neural networks mentioned in the other answer are more AI-like, but I don't know anything about them.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer, really helpful. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer *boo*. I will at least up vote it when I have enough reputation!

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the AI is to always seek to maintain the win conditions.

If it is practical (depending on how item locations are stored), at the start of each turn, the distance to all remaining items should be known to the AI. Ideally, this would be calculated once when the game is started, then simply "adjusted" based on where the AI moves, instead of recalculating at each turn. It also wouldn't be wise to have the AI do the same thing for the player if the AI isn't going to be only considering it's own situation.

From there is a matter of determining what item should be picked up as an optimization of the following considerations:

- What items and item categories does the AI currently have?
- What items and item categories does the player currently have?
- What items and item categories are near the AI?
- What items and item categories are near the Player?

Exactly how you do this largely depends on how difficult to beat you want the AI to be.

A simple way would be to use a greedy approach and simply go after the "current" best choice. This could be done by simply finding the closest item that is not in a category that the player is currently winning by so many items (probably 1-3). This produces an AI that tries to win, but doesn't think ahead making it rather easy to predict.

Allowing for the greedy algorithm to check multiple turns ahead will improve the algorithm, that and considering what the player will do will improve the algorithm further.

Heuristics will lead to a more realistic AI and hard to beat AI. Possibly even practically impossible to beat.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer, really helpful. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer *boo*. I will at least up vote it when I have enough reputation!